# Amazon S3 - External Bucket Association APi

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to associate a bucket in X account that is created by account Y

Account Y has given read and write permissons to X on the bucket via the Email ID

This was done using S3Fox - however when I log into X account I see no way to associate the external bucket.

I tried entering the bucket name as usual but didn't work

So I would like to code my own association via PHP and rest but can't find the call in the API docs - can someone send me a link or example code on how to create an external bucket in account X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Account X has to configure bucket from Y as "external bucket". but it is worse. the external bucket feature depends on the client software X uses. so the information on wich buckets X listen to is stored at X`s client not at S3. X have to use a s3 client wich supports external buckets.

Martin